# CSS vertical center background Div and image with respect to Front div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the attached layout working. I have container div that has the background image. I have other divs (child divs) that are inside the container div (color coded with brown in the image). I am trying to get child div overlay on top of parent div like in the image.  Wondering how I can achieve this. Can someone please help me with this?

[image]

My code looks like this

```css
.image-background-div {
    background-image: url('../images/resource_background.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
}
.front-container-div {
    top: -30px
}
```

```html
<div class="image-background-div">
   <div class="front-container-div">
         <h3>Title</h3>
         <p>Paragraph blocks</p>
         <div class="3-column-container">
            <div class="column-1">Column1</div>
            <div class="column-2">Column2</div>
            <div class="column-3">Column3</div>
         </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the CSS you already have? And with 75% covering you mean the front div should be 75% as wide as the div with bg-image?

Comment: Hi Luckyfella, thanks for the comment......Just added CSS. 75% covering means with respect to front div the background image should only get applied 75% vertically to the center.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on  `but only scaling/cropping to 70% of front div content vertically.`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion MeltingDog. Basically the top and bottom of the background image should be like how its in the sample layout.